# Using odeint to determine bifurcation

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I am attempting to get the data for the bifurcation diagram, namely the values of trigger [A] (which are specified by linspace of Aspace) which give steady-state (nullcline) values of [N] in this set of differential equations: 
[image]

As the set of equations is too long to attempt to get the nullclines by re-arranging, I am trying to use odeint to integrate over given time, and get the values of all d[x]/d(t) to 0, and return the values of [A] and [N] for those particular nullclines. In theory, this code should return the values expected, however it seems to kill the kernel without further explanation, preventing me from tracing down the issue. Please find the code below (don't get scared, most of it is just stating the variable values).

My code:

```
#basic conditions as specified in the material
OS = 0
O = 0
S= 0
N = 0
B = 0

n1 = 1*(10**-4)
a1 = 1
a2 = 0.01
a3 = 0.2
n2 = 1*(10**-7)
b1 = 0.0011
b2 = 0.001
b3 = 0.0007
n3 = 1*(10**-4)
c1 = 1
c2 = 0.01
c3 = 0.2
n4 = 1*(10**-7)
d1 = 0.0011
d2 = 0.001
d3 = 0.0007
n5 = 1*(10**-4)
e1 = 0.005
e2 = 0.1
n6 = 1*(10**-7)
f1 =0.001
f2 = 9.95*(10**-4)
f3 = 0.01
k1c = 0.05
k2c = 0.001
k3c = 5
g1 = 1
g2 = 1
g3 = 1
def differential_eq(y, t, A, B):
    O, S, OS, N = y
    dydt = np.empty(4)
    dydt[0] = ((n1 + a1*A + a2*OS + a3*OS*N)/(1 + n2 + b1*A + b2*OS + b3*OS*N)) - g1*O - k1c*O*S + k2c*OS
    dydt[1] = (n3 + c1*A + c2*OS + c3*OS*N)/(1 + n4 + d1*A + d2*OS + d3*OS*N) - g2*S - k1c*O*S + k2c*OS
    dydt[2] = k1c*O*S -k2c*OS - k3c*OS
    dydt[3] = ((n5 + e1*OS + e2*OS*N)/(1 + n6 +f1*OS + f2*OS*N + f3*B)) - g3*N
    return dydt

timepool =np.linspace(0,100,10)

def simulate(A):
A = A
y = (0,0,0,0)
B =0
solution = sp.odeint (differential_eq(y, timepool, A, B), (A, B), timepool)
    solution = sp.odeint (differential_eq, initial, timepool)
    if dydt[0] == 0 and dydt[1] ==0 and dydt[2] ==0 and dydt[3] ==0:
        print (A,N, solution)
        return (A, N)

Aspace = np.linspace(0,150,150)
for A in Aspace:
    simulate(A)
```

Now, this does not seem to work, and I see no indication of why, as it just kills the kernel: if anyone has any idea of why this is the case, please let me know.

Comment: Please read the [docstring of `odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).  The first two arguments of the function that defines the equations (your `differential_eq`) must be `y, t`, where `y` is the array containing the state variables (`[O, S, OS, N]`, in your case).  The docstring has an example; there are more examples in [the tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#ordinary-differential-equations-odeint) and in the [scipy cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: You can find more examples here on stackoverflow by searching for `[scipy] odeint`.

Comment: Even if I define the function as differential_eq(A, B, O, S, OS, N), and specify everything within 'initial' for odeint as 0 except A, which is in range of Aspace, it seems to kill the kernel. I either do not understand what is written in the docstring, or the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @JerichoJones could you provide a workable example? In your code `B` and `dydt` are not defined

Comment: @SaulloCastro, added B, dydt should be defined within differential_eq function as an empty np.array to start with and then should be filled in by the rest of the function based on particular equation resolved

Comment: The first argument of your function must be a *vector* of length 4.  The components of the vector are O, S, OS, and N.  The next argument must be `t`.  Additional parameters (e.g. A and B) follow `t`.  So your function must be `def differential_eq(y, t, A, B):`, and in the function, you can write `O, S, OS, N = y` to unpack the vector `y` into separate variables.

Comment: Also, the initial condition argument gives the initial values of O, S, OS and N, so it must also be a vector of length 4.  To pass the parameters A and B, use the `args` argument of `odeint`.  Take another look at the example in the `odeint` docstring to see how this is done.

Comment: One more thing: you have `timepool =np.linspace(100,100,10)`.  That just repeats the vaue 100 ten times.  Did you mean `timepool = np.linspace(0,100,10)`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: thank you, the timepool was wrong. Now odeint seems to throw a following error: 
     214                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
--> 215                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
    216     if output[-1] < 0:
    217         warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."
error: The function and its Jacobian must be callable functions.
Looking currently in doc for solution: if you have idea, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the parameters and the `args` argument:  when I wrote that comment, I wasn't thinking about all the other parameters.  If you prefer, you can skip the use of `args`, and just leave all the parameters global.

Comment: We won't know the reason for the error until we see the code.  Please edit the question to include the code and the error message.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, sure, apologies: the code is now edited. While it seems to me it does the same thing twice now (specifying the args for both function and odeint), I am not sure how this would the particular 'function and its Jacobian' error

Comment: The first argument to `odeint` is just the function name, with no parenthesis, like you had it before.  Again, see the example in the docstring, and the other examples I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I will not be able to do that, should I wish to specify A and B only within the function itself: otherwise the 'differential_eq() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'A' and 'B' ' error will show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the remarks in the comments and some more, your `simulate` function should look like

```python
def simulate(A):
    y = (0,0,0,0)
    B =0
    # parameter for the accuracy level
    eps = 1e-9
    # pass the correct arguments: first the function reference, then
    # initial point and sample times, the additional arguments and
    # the absolute and relative tolerances (they are combined as atol+rtol*(norm(y))
    solution = sp.odeint (differential_eq,y, timepool, args = (A, B), atol=1e-4*eps, rtol=1e-3*eps)
    y, t = solution[-1], timepool[-1]
    # compute the slopes at the last sample point by calling the ODE function
    dydt = differential_eq(y,t,A,B)
    # variables not explicitly declared global are local to the ODE function, 
    # they do not influence the global variables. 
    O, S, OS, N = y
    # never compare floating point numbers with "==" in numerics
    # always account for the floating point noise accumulated in the computation
    if max(abs(dydt)) < eps :
        #here print only the last sample point 
        print "%6.2f, %16.12f, %s"%(A, N, y)

    return (A, N)
```

which gives the result (shortened)

```
  0.00,   0.000099999991, [  9.99994911e-05   9.99994911e-05   9.99789864e-11   9.99999905e-05]
 10.00,   0.002883872464, [  7.25813895e+00   7.25813895e+00   5.26700470e-01   2.88387246e-03]
 20.00,   0.008780897525, [  1.21628435e+01   1.21628435e+01   1.47905181e+00   8.78089753e-03]
 30.00,   0.017500871488, [ 16.0785845   16.0785845    2.58469186   0.01750087]
 40.00,   0.030166487759, [ 19.40580443  19.40580443   3.76509943   0.03016649]
 50.00,   0.049390699930, [ 22.32996985  22.32996985   4.98527848   0.0493907 ]
 60.00,   0.081339098240, [ 24.95672023  24.95672023   6.22713342   0.0813391 ]
 70.00,   0.144113671629, [ 27.35699725  27.35699725   7.48255648   0.14411367]
100.00,  63.103453906658, [ 52.49789017  52.49789017  27.55477377  63.10345391]
110.00,  64.363708289042, [ 53.43024046  53.43024046  28.54219752  64.36370829]
120.00,  65.425943398185, [ 54.25586731  54.25586731  29.43110515  65.4259434 ]
130.00,  66.343605498371, [ 55.00078061  55.00078061  30.24480971  66.3436055 ]
140.00,  67.150809538919, [ 55.68201657  55.68201657  30.99866996  67.15080954]
150.00,  67.870747329663, [ 56.31143752  56.31143752  31.70343926  67.87074733]
```